# How to check either of variable exist in the gitlab rules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab rule condition like below.

```
'$ACTION && $REGION && $ROLE_ARN && $PACKAGEURL && $ACTION == "new" && $CLOUD_PLATFORM == "aws" && $ROLE_ARN != "" && $PACKAGEURL != "" && $REGION != ""'
```

Want to modify it a bit so that, it should check either the existence of PACKAGEURL or BUILDRPMREQUIRED above.

Tried keeping as below but getting run even if the PACKAGEURL or BUILDRPMREQUIRED not provided.

```
'$ACTION && $REGION && $ROLE_ARN && ($PACKAGEURL || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED) && $ACTION == "new" && $CLOUD_PLATFORM == "aws" && $ROLE_ARN != "" && ($PACKAGEURL != "" || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED != "") && $REGION != ""'
```

I kept in rule as below.

```
.ifawsfulldeploy:
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP && $ADMIN_SERVER_IP != ""'
      when: never
    - if: '$ACTION && $REGION && $ROLE_ARN && ($PACKAGE_URL || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED) && $ACTION == "new" && $CLOUD_PLATFORM == "aws" && $ROLE_ARN != "" && ($PACKAGE_URL != "" || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED != "") && $REGION != ""'
      when: always
```

Other rules should be there, with only variables I am getting syntax error.

```
.ifawsfulldeploy:
  rules:
    - if: '$ADMIN_SERVER_IP && $ADMIN_SERVER_IP != ""'
      when: never
    - if: '$ACTION && $REGION && $ROLE_ARN && ( $PACKAGE_URL || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED ) && $ACTION == "new" && $CLOUD_PLATFORM == "aws" && $ROLE_ARN != "" && ( $PACKAGE_URL != "" || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED != "" ) && $REGION != ""'
      when: always
```

And in my job.

```
  only:
    variables:
      - $PACKAGE_URL
      - $BUILDRPMREQUIRED
  extends:
    - .ifawsfulldeploy
```

Answer (score 6):

im new in Gitlab but i had the same question and

```
$FOO != null
```

condition helped me.
Hope it helped u too!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a rule just for the variables?
Like this example from the Gitlab docs:

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo This rule uses parentheses.
  only:
    variables:
      - ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop") && $MY_VARIABLE
```

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#only-variables--except-variables-examples

Comment: it seems we can keep only one variable

Comment: can you check the content  I added at the end of post now

Comment: What about if you add them like:

`only:
   variables:
      - ($PACKAGE_URL || $BUILDRPMREQUIRED)`

And remove them from the rule above?
(Sorry about the formatting, can't figure out how to format the code properly).

Comment: Also, you have a mistake, `extends:` shouldn't point to the same job name, it's circular reference. @Jor-El

Comment: sorry for confusion both are at different places, edited the post.

Comment: And still doesn't work

Comment: Can you please share the whole file? Not just the rules? What else do you have in the job that extends the rule? In the original I mean, before trying with the variables.

Comment: nothing else, only these rules extends

Comment: You can't have jobs without a script element (or before_script/after_script), unless it's a trigger job, so maybe that's why you were getting the syntax errors.